# Using ApiControllerAttribute without using RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, attributerouting

In ASP.NET Core (v 2.1.5) you can create controllers without having them inherit from `Controller` class (as you know). And if you do, you have to use `RouteAttribute` to define your routes. But, I'm interested if we can use implicit routing (and not attribute routing) along with `ApiController` attribute together. Example: Having this implicit routing in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => 
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute("api_default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

And this `Controller` class

```
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController 
{
    [HttpGet] 
    public string Get(int id) => id.ToString();
}
```

Will throw this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Action
> 'TestApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get' does not have an attribute
> route. Action methods on controllers annotated with
> ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed.

Is there a way to avoid the exception?

Comment: It is referring to the `[Http*]` attributes

Comment: @Nkosi I did use `[HttpGet]`. Please see the update. The error is still there.

Comment: Any reason not wanting to inherit from Api/Controller? I mean, you still have to use a lot of ASP.NET Core classes anyway

Comment: according to docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-requirement `Attribute routing becomes a requirement when using [ApiController]`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> But, I'm interested if we can use implicit routing (and not attribute routing) along with `ApiController` attribute together.

According to official documentation

> Attribute routing becomes a requirement. For example:
>
> ```
> [Route("api/[controller]")]
> [ApiController]
> public class ValuesController
> ```
>
> ***Actions are inaccessible via conventional routes defined in UseMvc or
>   by UseMvcWithDefaultRoute in Startup.Configure.***

Note: ***emphasis mine***

Reference [Build web APIs with ASP.NET Core: Attribute routing requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-requirement)

Comment: But why?  There seems to be absolutely no justification for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Also use the `[Route("api/VillaAPI")]` in Controller Name hard.